# python regex of a date in some text

Tags: python, regex

How can I find as many date patterns as possible from a text file by python? The date pattern is defined as:

```
dd mmm yyyy
  ^   ^
  |   |
  +---+--- spaces
```

where:

- **dd** is a two digit number
- **mmm** is three-character English month name (e.g. Jan, Mar, Dec)
- **yyyy** is four digit year
- there are two **spaces** as separators

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not following you. Are you looking to grep for patterns of dates or for the dates according to a fixed single pattern?

Comment: I want to extract the actual dates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way to find all dates matching your pattern

```
re.findall(r'\d\d\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4}', text)
```

But after WilhelmTell's comment on your question, I'm also wondering whether this it what you were really asking for...

Answer (score 9):

Use the calendar module to give you a little global awareness:

```
date_expr = r"\d{2} (?:%s) \d{4}" % '|'.join(calendar.month_abbr[1:])
print date_expr
print re.findall(date_expr, source_text)
```

For me, this creates a date_expr like:

```
"\d{2} (:?Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{4}"
```

But if I change my locale using the locale module:

```
locale.setlocale(0, "fr")
```

I now search for months in French:

```
"\d{2} (?:janv.|févr.|mars|avr.|mai|juin|juil.|août|sept.|oct.|nov.|déc.) \d{4}"
```

Hmm, this is the first time I ever tried French month abbreviations, I may need to do some cleanup:

```
date_expr = r"\d{2} (?:%s) \d{4}" % '|'.join(
    m.title().rstrip('.') for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:])
```

Now I get:

```
"\d{2} (?:Janv|Févr|Mars|Avr|Mai|Juin|Juil|Août|Sept|Oct|Nov|Déc) \d{4}"
```

And now my script will run for my Gallic friends as well, with really very little trouble.

(You may wonder why I had to slice the month_abbr list from [1:] - this list begins with an empty string in position 0, so that if you use find() to look up a particular month abbreviation, you will get back a number from 1-12, instead of from 0-11.)

-- Paul

Comment: This is why I prefer to use the RE to validate the basic format (_day month-abbrev year_) and then let `strptime` take care of the localization of the month.  If you are really interested, you can use some of the locale-aware options to account for differences in M-D-Y ordering as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly more complete example.  The regexp will match more than just valid date value.  `datetime.strptime` will fail to parse anything that is not valid and raise a `ValueError`.  If the date is parsed, then you have a full `datetime` object that gives you access to a lot of functionality.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import re
>>> dates = []
>>> patn = re.compile(r'\d{2} \w{3} \d{4}')
>>> fh = open('inputfile')
>>> for line in fh:
...   for match in patn.findall(line):
...     try:
...       val = datetime.strptime(match, '%d %b %Y')
...       dates.append(val)
...     except ValueError:
...       pass # ignore, this isn't a date
...
```

I imagine that this can be collapsed into nice tight code with comprehensions if you are so inclined.

Comment: appreciated! how can I concat 'val's into an array in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

allmatches = re.findall(r'\d\d \w\w\w \d\d\d\d', "string to match")
```

Comment: Seriously? -1? Any reason other than '\w\w\w' probably isn't that great of a way to match a month?  It **IS** what the guy asked for in his 'dd mmm yyyy' syntax.  While it's not ideal, I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Hi, though very late it may give any three alphanumeric characters which can be 
very random? correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this for completelly

```
date = re.findall(r'\d\d\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}', text)
print date
['30 November 2010 14:20', '30 November 2010 14:24']
```