# python regex of a date in some text, enclosed by two keywords

Tags: python, regex

This is Part 2 of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770040/python-regex-of-a-date-in-some-text/2770064#2770064) and thanks very much for David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770040/python-regex-of-a-date-in-some-text/2770062#2770062). What if I need to extract dates which are bounded by two keywords?

Example:

```
text = "One 09 Jun 2011 Two 10 Dec 2012 Three 15 Jan 2015 End"

Case 1 bounding keyboards: "One" and "Three"
Result expected: ['09 Jun 2011', '10 Dec 2012']

Case 2 bounding keyboards: "Two" and "End"
Result expected: ['10 Dec 2012', '15 Jan 2015']
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Horace did you ask your question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770040/python-regex-of-a-date-in-some-text

Comment: @Lirik, the second question adds one more condition, so I better separate the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with two regular expressions.  One regex gets the text between the two keywords.  The other regex extracts the dates.

```
match = re.search(r"\bOne\b(.*?)\bThree\b", text, re.DOTALL)
if match:
    betweenwords = match.group(1)
    dates = re.findall(r'\d\d (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{4}', betweenwords)
```

Comment: it works, thx! except re.findal(..., text) should be re.findall(..., betweenwords)
btw, is the first and last "\b" required in the first regex?

Comment: I have corrected the `findall` parameter.  All 4 `\b` are required if you want your words to be matched as whole words.  E.g. `\bEnd\b` cannot match `Ending`.  If you don't care whether your two keywords are whole or partial words, then you can omit all 4 `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to worry about the keywords?  Can you ensure that the keywords will not change?

If not, the exact same solution from the previous question can solve this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "One 09 Jun 2011 Two 10 Dec 2012 Three 15 Jan 2015 End"
>>> match = re.findall(r'\d\d\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4}', text)
>>> match
['09 Jun 2011', '10 Dec 2012', '15 Jan 2015']
```

If you really only need two of the dates, you could just use list slicing:

```
>>> match[:2]
['09 Jun 2011', '10 Dec 2012']
>>> match[1:]
['10 Dec 2012', '15 Jan 2015']
```

Comment: The keywords (user-defined) are important for excluding some dates which are not inside the relevant part of a document.

Comment: So the keywords will be different and will have variable lengths?  You'll have to use greedy matching.  Alpha only, or alphanumeric?  These are all important considerations when building your patterns.

Comment: Please consider the bounding keywords to be 2 constant strings.