# Extract Different Date Structures with Text Using RE- Python

Tags: regex, string, date, python-3.5

I have strings that have dates in different formats. For example,

```
sample_str_1 = 'this amendment of lease, made and entered as of the  10th day of august, 2016,   by and between john doe and jane smith'
```

Also, another string that has the date in it as,

```
sample_str_2 ='this agreement, made and entered as of May 1, 2016, between john doe and jane smith'
```

In order to extract just the date from the first string, I did something like this,

```
match = re.findall(r'\S+d{4}\s+', sample_str_1)
```

this gives an empty list.

For the second string, I used the same method as I used for first string and getting an empty string.

I also, tried `datefinder` module and it gave me an output like this,

```
import datefinder
match = datefinder.find_dates(sample_str_1)

for m in match:
    print(m)

>> 2016-08-01 00:00:00
```

Above output is wrong, which should be `2016-08-10 00:00:00`

I tried another way using this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770040/python-regex-of-a-date-in-some-text)

```
match = re.findall(r'\d{2}(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\d{4}',sample_str_1)
```

This again gave me an empty list.

How can I extract dates like that from a string? Is there a generic method to extract dates that have text and digits? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser) package. Reinventing the wheel here doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @ctwheels That didn't wordk, I used `date_parse = DateDataParser().get_date_data(sample_str_1)` and I got `{'date_obj': None, 'locale': None, 'period': 'day'}`

Comment: Do you only need to match the specific phrases `[day]st/nd/rd/th day of [month], [year]` and `[month] [day], [year]`? There are many other ways to format a date.

Comment: You have only two formats of date `10th day of august, 2016` and `May 1, 2016`?

Comment: @CAustin yes, that is one format and string 2 has a different format.

Comment: @S.Jovan yes, for now, I have those two formats and if I can extract them, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`(?:(\d{1,2})(?:th|nd|rd).* ([a-z]{3})[a-z]*|([a-z]{3})[a-z]* (\d{1,2})),\s*(\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/kKm1Sm/2)

**Python code**:

```
regex = re.compile('(?:(\d{1,2})(?:th|nd|rd).* ([a-z]{3})[a-z]*|([a-z]{3})[a-z]* (\d{1,2})),\s*(\d{4})', re.I)

for x in regex.findall(text):
    if x[0] == '':
        date = '-'.join(filter(None, x))
    else:
        date = '%s-%s-%s' % (x[1],x[0],x[4])

    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%b-%d-%Y').date())
```

Output:

```
2016-08-10
2016-05-01
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/byXva2)

Comment: this works great. What can I do if I have `2nd`, `3rd` etc. I tried to add  `(?:(\d{1,2})th|nd|rd.* (..` it prints blank. How can I add that? (As I am a new user, I can not upvote yet, as you deserve one)