# remove recognized date from string

Tags: python, date, python-dateutil

As input I have several strings containing dates in different formats like

- "Peter drinks tea at **16:45**"
- "My birthday is on **08-07-1990**"
- "On **Sat 11 July** I'll be back home"

I use `dateutil.parser.parse` to recognize the dates in the strings.
In the next step I want to remove the dates from the strings. Result should be

- "Peter drinks tea at "
- "My birthday is on "
- "On  I'll be back home"

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`fuzzy_with_tokens`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) option to `dateutil.parser.parse`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

dtstrs = [
    "Peter drinks tea at 16:45",
    "My birthday is on 08-07-1990",
    "On Sat 11 July I'll be back home",
    ]

out = [
    parse(dtstr, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
    for dtstr in dtstrs
]
```

Result:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 16, 45), ('Peter drinks tea at ',)),
 (datetime.datetime(1990, 8, 7, 0, 0), ('My birthday is on ',)),
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 11, 0, 0), ('On ', ' ', " I'll be back home"))]
```

When `fuzzy_with_tokens` is true, the parser returns a tuple of a `datetime` and a tuple of ignored tokens (with the used tokens removed). You can join them back into a string like this:

```
>>> ['<missing>'.join(x[1]) for x in out]
['Peter drinks tea at ',
 'My birthday is on ',
 "On <missing> <missing> I'll be back home"]
```

I'll note that the fuzzy parsing logic is not amazingly reliable, because it's very difficult to pick out only valid components from a string and use them. If you change the person drinking tea to someone named April, for example:

```
>>> dt, tokens = parse("April drinks tea at 16:45", fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
>>> print(dt)
2018-04-17 16:45:00
>>> print('<missing>'.join(tokens))
 drinks tea at
```

So I would urge some caution with this approach (though I can't really recommend a *better* approach, this is just a hard problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you define a function that would validate a string as a date or not, we could do this in a one-liner

```
from dateutil import parser

data = ['Peter drinks tea at 16:45', 'My birthday is on 08-07-1990', "On Sat 11 July I'll be back home"]

def is_valid_date(date_str):
    try:
        parser.parse(date_str)
        return True
    except:
        return False

new_list = [' '.join([w for w in line.split() if not is_valid_date(w)]) for line in data]
print(new_list)
# ['Peter drinks tea at', 'My birthday is on', "On I'll be back home"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.findall() method for find the dates then split it from your string.
I think the code in link in below can solve your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770062/9721027

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_dates(sentence):
"""remove the dates like Mar 30  2013"""
sentence = re.sub('(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{4}', ' ', sentence)
return sentence
```

Test:

```
remove_dates(' good Mar 30 2013 day')
```

' good   day'