# Remove dates from list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
rand_strings = [
        "Hi 06/02/2020 my name is Arjun", 
        "Oh 2992 that's nice", 
        "Some other string 2019-05-12",
]
```

I want to remove only the dates of these two formats from them. Not [all recognized dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384426/remove-recognized-date-from-string). This is my desired output:

```
rand_strings = [
        "Hi my name is Arjun", 
        "Oh 2992 that's nice", 
        "Some other string " #whitespace doesn't matter
]
```

The list is thousands of elements long and several of them have these dates to be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510)

Comment: The main challenge here is deciding "what is a date", or in other words, what date formats are you dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Use regex expressions to match **exactly** those 2 types:

```py
import re

rand_strings = [
        "Hi 06/02/2020 my name is Arjun", 
        "Oh 2992 that's nice", 
        "Some other string 2019-05-12",
]

rand_strings = [re.sub(r"(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", "", s) for s in rand_strings]
```

You can then remove extra whitespace characters.